# How to restore Google backup on Android 8.1.0?

Tags: backup, restore, 8.1-oreo

My Android 11 'phone just died. I had Google Backup running.

I have an old Android 8.1.0 device lying around, which will do until I can buy a new 'phone.

There's lots of advice out there, but it all seems to mention menus that I don't have.

How do I restore my apps, contacts, photos, settings, etc onto the Android 8.1.0 device?3

Comment: Restoring a backup is part of the first-time initialization process after a factory reset.

Comment: Can you elucidate? I did a factory reset, then logged into my Google account. How do you get my apps, contacts, photos, etc, back?